# How to fill the pixels of an image in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to fill in the "pixels" of an example image: a 480x800 image I would like to match up to 800x800 but without changing the width or height, I would like to do so by adding more pixels but a black color without the image being distorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for some thing like [9 patch feature](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html) 
This will give you the ability to specify how image will grow,so you can start from there.
[image]

Comment: it's a possibility, but is there any way to add pixels of a color to the image?

Comment: Using 9 patch you can edit the image and add this pixel manually and then define the role for 9 patch to stretch this pixel .